# Loop order issue

Tags: python, loops

Hopefully this will be my last question today :)

I have a csv file that has a lot of lines with data such as:

```
{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","age":30}
{"first_name":"Tim","last_name":"Johnson","age":34}
```

I am using this code to grab the first names from the file:

```
with open("c:\\newgood.csv", "r") as fo:
    for line in fo:
        match = re.search('first_name"(.*?)"(.*?)"', line)
        if match:
            results = match.group(2)
        else:
            print('None')
        print results
```

This works except every time I hit a line with no first_name it goes back through the loop and doesn't print correctly.  My first name records for example in the file are:

> John Tim Rob Lori Mel (no record) (no record) Carrie Trevor

When I use the code above, I get:

> John Tim Rob Lori Mel None Mel None Mel Carrie Trevor

How do I correct the code above to iterate through the lines and print none where there is no first_name and not loop back through incorrectly like it is doing?

I really only need to know how to get the above code to loop through the lines correctly and not try a different way due to other factors.  Thanks!

Comment: I suggest using a debugger to step through your code. You will see that `print results` is executed every time the loop iterates. This explains the behavior you see.

Comment: It only looks like it's a loop order issue because you print `result` even if it's not being set when it doesn't find anything. Your `print results` should be after the `results = match...` statement within the first clause of the `if`.

Comment: Isn't this based off your previous question... And if that was solved so you can convert the above to dictionaries, can't you just do `if first_name not in line_as_dict` or similar?

Comment: I used the solution on the last question before I saw his edit for the dictionaries.  I am in a bit of a time crunch, but will check that out as well.  I now have all of the data I need in the correct order.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace the print statement in the else by an affectation:

```
with open("c:\\newgood.csv", "r") as fo:
    for line in fo:
        match = re.search('first_name"(.*?)"(.*?)"', line)
        if match:
            results = match.group(2)
        else:
            results = 'None'
        print results
```

#### Explanation

With your code, when there's no first name found, you're printing 'None' and after you're leaving the else block. Right. But then, the interpretor hits the `print results` line, but for him the last results found was a the previous line, so it's repeat the previous results, which was *Mel* in your case.

So you need to change results at each loop to be sure to print the first name OR the 'None' string only.

Answer (score 1):

`print results` executes every time the loop repeats. Since you only change the value of `results` in the `if` clause, you will see a name repeated whenever the current input does not contain a name.